# Check a CNAME exist in a hosted zone in aws route53

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

How can I check if a CNAME already exists in the hosted zone?

```
client = Aws::Route53::Client.new(region: "us-west-2", access_key_id: aws_access_key_id, secret_access_key: aws_secret_access_key, session_token: aws_session_token)
```

This gives me all the hosted zone. I have searched a lot but I couldn't find any method which checks if a CName exists in a hosted zone. The only [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Route53/Client.html) which I found which has all the methods related to aws route53

```
client.list_hosted_zones.hosted_zones
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[list_resource_record_sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Route53/Client.html#list_resource_record_sets-instance_method) is the SDK method to use.

First you need to get a list of resource records from the zone using `list_resource_record_sets`. The query is a bit weird the results come in alpha order and you need to supply a `start_record_name` if you supply a `start_record_type`.

```
client = Aws::Route53::Client.new(region: "us-west-2", access_key_id: aws_access_key_id, secret_access_key: aws_secret_access_key, session_token: aws_session_token)

hosted_zone_id = "WHATEVERONEIDIS"

records = client.list_resource_record_sets(hosted_zone_id: hosted_zone_id, 
           start_record_type: "CNAME", 
           start_record_name: "A"
           max_items: 1)
```

this will get a single record starting with the CNAME if is exists.

then you just need to check the results.

```
cname = records.resource_record_sets.select{ |r| r.type ==  "CNAME"}.first
```

if cname is nil -- there is no cname record.